# How to scroll to bottom using keyboard in file explorer windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, scrolling

I don't have a dedicated keyboard having all the keys like <kbd>Page up</kbd>, <kbd>Page down</kbd> but I'm pretty sure these keys can somehow be used in the smaller keyboard of a normal 15 inch laptop. My question here is specific to a keyboard shortcut for scrolling to the end directly in file explorer windows 10. I know scrolling one file at once can be done by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow. But I don't want to keep holding that and waiting to reach it to the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried to press End key?

Comment: Try `<ctrl><pgdn>` or `<ctrl><end>`

Comment: What is your keyboard that does not have PgUp, PdDn, and those keys. They may require a Shift or like key to access, but the main keys should be there.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio There is no dedicated end key on my keyboard. Though, 'end' is written on the '1-number key' of the numeric keypad on the right side. I don't know how to use it. And again, end is written on the right arrow key too. :)

Comment: @John Thanks. It worked. Shift + 1(end) scrolls right to the bottom. Shift +7(home) scrolls right to the top. Shift +3 and 9 simply scroll the page down and up respectively.

Comment: You press numlock key to switch between numbers and home/end etc. Each numpad key emulates two keys.

Comment: @user1292580 Thanks. I didn't know that Numlock key serves this function in spite of blocking all the keys under its control.

Comment: IBM controlled hardware standards. Each key costs more. So first IBM computers (you use their derivatives now) had 84 keys so cursor keys and numpad were combined. As numbers were at the top as well it was envisaged that they would be cursor keys for most and data entry keys when required. The Ctrl+Alt+Delete keys is known in Windows as SAS (Secure Attention Sequence). IBM refused to add an extra key to the keyboard as Microsoft wanted because it cost to much. So we have to press 3 keys at once instead of one key.